# HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync content empty

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to send a complex data type from one process to another using ASP.net MVC.  For some reason the receiving end always receives blank (zero/default) data.

My sending side:

```
static void SendResult(ReportResultModel result)
{
    //result contains valid data at this point

    string portalRootPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webHost"];
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(portalRootPath);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage resp = client.PostAsJsonAsync("Reports/MetricEngineReport/MetricResultUpdate", result).Result;
    if (!resp.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    //I've confirmed this isn't happening by putting a breakpoint in here.
    }
}
```

My receiving side, in a different class, running in a different process on my local machine:

```
public class MetricEngineReportController : Controller
{
    ...
    [HttpPost]
    public void MetricResultUpdate(ReportResultModel result)
    {
        //this does get called, but
        //all the guids in result are zero here :(
    }
    ...
}
```

My model is a bit complicated:

```
[Serializable]
public class ReportResultModel
{
    public ReportID reportID {get;set;}
    public List<MetricResultModel> Results { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class MetricResultModel
{
    public Guid MetricGuid { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public MetricResultModel(MetricResultModel other)
    {
        MetricGuid = other.MetricGuid;
        Value = other.Value;
    }

    public MetricResultModel(Guid MetricGuid, int Value)
    {
        this.MetricGuid = MetricGuid;
        this.Value = Value;
    }

}

[Serializable]
public struct ReportID
{
    public Guid _topologyGuid;
    public Guid _matchGuid;
}
```

Any idea why the data's not arriving?
Any help would be much appreciated...

P.S. For some reason I can't seem to catch the http POST message on fiddler, not sure why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was twofold:

1. I needed to specify the type in my JSON post like this:

   ```
   HttpResponseMessage resp = client.PostAsJsonAsync<MetricResultModel>("Reports/MetricEngineReport/MetricResultUpdate", result.Results[0]).Result;
   ```
2. The components of my model did not have default constructors, which is necessary for the JSON deserialization on the receiving end.

Comment: Thank you. I had been struggling with something similar for days and `1.` solved it (already had default constructors).

Answer (score 6):

Try using "[FromBody]" parameter in Controller's Action. As you post data is passed to body not in url.

```
[HttpPost]
public void MetricResultUpdate([FromBody] ReportResultModel result)
{
    //this does get called, but
    //all the guids in result are zero here :(
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. It seems that the `content-length` header is set to 0 when using the default `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method, which causes the server to ignore the request body.

My solution was to install the `System.Net.Http.Json` nuget package that uses the new `System.Text.Json` serializer.

When you add `using System.Net.Http.Json;`, you should be able to use the new extension method `PostAsJsonAsync` that works (sets the `content-length` header) properly.

```
namespace System.Net.Http.Json
{
    public static class HttpClientJsonExtensions
    {
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<TValue>(this HttpClient client, string? requestUri, TValue value, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri, value, null, cancellationToken);
        }

    }
}
```