# Object null in WebApi method after PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-post, asp.net-web-api2

I am posting an object to a WebApi method. I'm using `PostAsJsonAsync` to do this.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string token, ServiceCall call)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.SetBearerToken(token);

    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(Uri + "id/nestedcall", call);

    return response;
}
```

The object `call` that I'm passing is not null when I post it.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("id/nestedcall")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> NestedCall([FromBody]ServiceCall call)
{
    // call is null here
}
```

However it is null in my API method. I can't seem to work out why as all of the examples I've followed use this format.

Why isn't the call object being picked up by the web api?

**Edit**

Here is the `ServiceCall` object. It is in a separate class library and a reference is included in both the web application and the API.

```
public class ServiceCall
{
    public ServiceCall(Service service, string grantType)
    {
        ClientId = service.Id;
        ClientSecret = service.Secret;
        Uri = service.Uri;
        Scope = service.Scope;
        GrantType = grantType;
    }

    public ServiceCall(string clientid, string clientsecret, string uri, string scope, string grantType)
    {
        ClientId = clientid;
        ClientSecret = clientsecret;
        Uri = uri;
        Scope = scope;
        GrantType = grantType;
    }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    public string Scope { get; set; }
    public string GrantType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste the exception message. However it seems that your model bindings is not working

Comment: Also run it in debug mode and step into the code you will find out more about the data you are sending

Comment: He does not get an exception message, just receives  null, happened to me a few times,  and it can have different causes. Since you say the same signature of methods works in other cases, I would ask you if you send and receive the exactly sams type, or just classes with the same name, but in different namespaces. If second variant, please check if you have TypeNameHandling set to auto or to all, I guess in Global config, if I remember well.

Comment: @meJustAndrew They are indeed the same type.

Comment: @Arsene I don't get an exception, that's not the issue. Also I have stepped through the entire process in debug mode. That's how I am sure what I am sending is not null when I send it.

Comment: @Jon Please show us the ServiceCall class

Comment: What you could try is serialize "mannualy" using JsonConvert and expect the parameter as string. Yhen deserialize mannualy. I know this is not the solution, but it will help you debug.

Comment: @Dudemanword Now included above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync content empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535415/httpclient-postasjsonasync-content-empty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Prefix Stackify I was able to diagnose that the serialiser was throwing an exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Core.Models.ServiceCall. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'ClientId', line 1, position 12.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize
```

However, very helpfully, rather than tell me that an exception occurred the controller simply gave me a null object.

As hinted by the exception the solution is to add a default constructor (or at least one the serialiser can understand).

```
public ServiceCall()
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you - this helped me get to the answer. In my case, my class was in a class library project and was marked as internal, so the Web API service couldn't access it to fill the values.

Answer (score 8):

I have seen Object null in WebApi method after **PostAsJsonAsync** due to serialization. 
Better to use **PostAsync** like below :

```
        var obj = new MyClass()
        {
            MyProperty = 11
        };

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string inputJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); 
            HttpContent inputContent = new StringContent(inputJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response1 = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:60909/api/home/Test", inputContent).Result;
            if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: I had forgotten the Encoding.UTF8

Answer (score 0):

looks like the JSON serialization may be failing. BTW, remove that `[FromBody]` and try without it like below. `PostAsJsonAsync` method serializes the `ServiceCall` object to `JSON` and then sends the JSON payload in a POST request.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> NestedCall(ServiceCall call)
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I've already tried it without `[FromBody]` as it's something I added when it didn't work initially. However, a lot of examples I saw did use it.

Answer (score 0):

I run into exactly the same problem and had to do this to solve it:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.SetBearerToken(token);
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(call), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(Uri + "id/nestedcall", content);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: what are you doing with `content `?